# curly quotation in ORACLE database turns to \2019 in csv file when data is extracted via cx_oracle

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, oracle, pipeline, cx-oracle

I am designing a data pipeline that grabs data from an oracle data base, process the data on python and then write them on a temp csv and push them to a PostgreSQL data base using copy_from in psycog2. I am writing the file to a csv file because data is large and I want to improve the performance of my pipeline by writing into postgresql db from text file.

The problem that I have is a row in my oracle data base that has curly quotation in it and postgresql is not happy with it because csv file has some invalid byte sequence  `0x81` in it .

These are the steps that I do to run my pipeline. First I set my cx_oralce connection as followed:

### cx_oracle settings

```
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_5")

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(r'*****', ****, service_name=r'****') 

conn_oracle = cx_Oracle.connect( user =db_info['oracleDBInfo']['username'], password=db_info['oracleDBInfo']['password'], dsn=dsn_tns) 

cur_oracle = conn_oracle.cursor()
```

then run my query which is something like this. I have used a shorter version here.

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE(ASCIISTR(act_d.ACTIVITY_NAME), '\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}', '') AS ACTIVITY_NAME
FROM ACTIVITY_F act_f
```

then by calling

```
cur_oracle.execute(query_string)
dt = cur_oracle.fetchall()
col_names = [row[0] for row in cur_oracle.description]
dframe = pd.DataFrame(dt,columns = col_names)
```

write `dframe` into a csv file using this method

```
with open('dframe.csv',"a") as f:
  dframe.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False,encoding="utf-8")
```

then call copy_from function as followed

```
def copy_from_file(conn, path_to_file, table):
    """
    Here we are going save the dataframe on disk as 
    a csv file, load the csv file  
    and use copy_from() to copy it to the table
    """

    f = open(path_to_file, 'r',encoding = "utf-8",errors = "replace")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.copy_from(f, table, sep=",")
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        #os.remove(tmp_df)
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    print("copy_from_file() done")
    cursor.close()
```

and as a result i get the error saying

```
Error: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x81
CONTEXT:  COPY course_activities_cache, line 9002
```

when I look at the line in the csv file i see
this

```
MindTapDon\2019t forget to register for MindTap, you...
```

the \2019 is shown as a curly quotation in oracle data base when I look at it with DBeaver. I have also changed the nencoding settings in cx_oracle connect to `utf-16-be` as my data base  `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is `[('AL16UTF16',)]`, but that did not help. As a side note, the column that I am extracting my data from is a NVARCHAR2 column in the oracle data base.

I appreciate your thoughts and comments on this.

### Update - offending row as bytes - part of line is omitted because it includes personal data.

[image]

Comment: I don't know any encoding where character U+2019 would start with 0x81, so I guess you must have mangled the data somehow. Can you show the offending line 9002 as bytes?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you for your response. I have included bytes representation of the row in my post.

Comment: Seems like `ASCIISTR` is called to introduce the backslash escape sequences, but they are not stripped from the string. Why don't you just leave non-ASCII characters as they are?

Comment: I tried to use plain string without running any regex manipulation and I get \x92 in the file also get an error  saying  something like data has extra column in line 9002.

Comment: It should work fine as long as you export the data as UTF-8 from Oracle and set the PostgreSQL client encoding to `UTF8`. If you run into problems there, perhaps you should ask a question about those problems. Have you considered using oracle_fdw to transfer the data?

Comment: That is another problem that I have. I basically have no control over encoding when data is transferred from  oracle to my local environment. I have not heard of oracle_fdw. Is it a python module?

Comment: Oh yes, you do have control over the encoding by setting the `encoding` parameter of [`cx_Oracle.connect()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect). But that defaults to `UTF-8` anyway, so you should be good.

Comment: That is what I meant. Other encodings are not working.  I mean when I set it to WINDOWS-1252 it seems that it is not really working. I even used nencoding and set it to utf-16 because it is my character set for nvarchar column, but it did not work. My impression is that something is missing in transferring data from server to my local environment but I can not figure it out.

Comment: It is mentioned in cx_oracle documentation that if data base character set and your client character set are different then data will be missed. I think that is the source of my problem.

Comment: Of course you don't set it to WINDOWS-1252. There is no reasonable encoding except UTF-8. "It did not work" -> start a new question and describe the problem in ample detail there.